# Memoizing Child Components that have API Calls

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component which renders sections based on a state variable.
Each section is a child component.

e.g. code snippet of the render function in the parent component

```
  const renderActiveSection = (section: SectionsType): JSX.Element => {
    switch (section) {
      case 'A':
        return <A />
      case 'B':
        return <B />
    }
  }
```

Child components are `A` and `B`. They each have API calls when the child component is first rendered via a `useEffect`.

Each time the `section` state variable changes, the child components are re-rendered. I get that. I'm attempting to use `useMemo` to memorize the child components like so:

```
const AMemo = useMemo(A, [])
const BMemo = useMemo(B, [])
```

and use those instead of `<A />` and `<B />`. But this doesn't work.

Note that using a dummy function for `A` and `B` that don't have API calls **does** work.

What's the best practice here? Should I just cache the API responses instead?